# Create instances of a class with an without implementing an interface

Tags: java

Is there a way to do that without using a subclass that extends said class and using a implement?

I have something like this:

```
abstract class A{ }

class B extends A{ }

class C extends A{ }

class D extends A{ }

Interface X { }

Interface Y { }

Interface Z { }

B instanceOfB = new B() //doesn't use interface

B instanceOfBUsingX = new B() //it must use interface X
```

I don't want to create a `class B_using_X extends B implements X` because I would need to make every combination possible.
also both declarations must be of (or be treated as) the same class type (I think this shouldn't be a problem if I declare methods that expects A types)

Comment: You can't assign an instance of type `X` to a reference of type `B` unless `X` is also a `B`.

Comment: I'm afraid to say I have no idea what it is you are trying to do. You write `B instanceOfBUsingX = new B() //it must use interface X` **but none of your classes implement any interface at all!**. `B` doesn't implement `X` because nowhere in your code have you told that one of your classes in the hierarchy `implements X`. So where do you expect this B that somehow implements X to come from?

Comment: Expanding on @OHGODSPIDERS's comment: what does "use interface X" mean to you? I feel there's a fundamental misunderstanding here.

Comment: A is Product, B is Milk, X is Discount, a product can have discounts or not, but only can use discounts methods if it has implemented the discount (discounts are only managed through interface)

Comment: Do you want some kind of duck typing, where `interface X` prescibes some `x()` method, and `class B` happens to have such method, and you really just don't want to write out the `implements X`?

Comment: It sounds like you want to be able to dynamically add attributes to your instance. Inheritance can't do that — it's something that's checked at compile-time. I would model this using composition instead: have Product have a nullable Discount field (or possibly-empty collection, if you can have multiple discounts on a single product). You may want to model it differently altogether, too: have separate Products and Discounts (where a Discount references the Product it's for), and then at checkout time find all the Discounts that apply to a given Product, and apply them.

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding what interfaces are for. If class B implements interface X, then that is like saying "B is an X". In your case "Milk is a Discount" does make no sense at all, hence Milk implementing Discount as an Interface makes also no sense. Milk can have a discount. So make the Discount a property of your Milk class by giving it a field `private Discount discount` for example.

Comment: Or, don't have a field to store the discount - the discount isn't a property of the item I'm buying, it's a property of the collection of things I'm buying, at the point I pay (e.g. think of a 3-for-2 deal - which of the items does the discount belong to?). In some sense, the discount is a property of your cart, not the items in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't implement an interface as the instance level, only the class level. The accepted solution to this problem is called the [adapter pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern).

Assume we have this pre-existing class that doesn't know about our special interface.

```
public class SomeClass {

  public void doTheThing() {
    ...
  }

}
```

Then we want it to implement a new interface we just came up with.

```
public interface CanDoTheThing {
  public void doTheThing();
}
```

Then we make a wrapper class that *contains* an instance of `SomeClass` and calls the right method.

```
public class SomeClassAdapter implements CanDoTheThing {
  private SomeClass impl;

  public SomeClassAdapter(SomeClass impl) {
    this.impl = impl;
  }

  @Override
  public void doTheThing() {
    this.impl.doTheThing();
  }

}
```

Now when we want to pass an instance `someInstance` of `SomeClass` to a function that needs an instance of `CanDoTheThing`, we instead pass `new SomeClassAdapter(someInstance)`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're looking for a way to have a class that extends another class while also implementing certain interfaces, without explicitly creating a new subclass for each combination of the base class and interfaces. However, in most programming languages, including Java, you cannot directly achieve this without creating specific subclasses or modifying the class hierarchy.

In your example, if you want both instanceOfB and instanceOfBUsingX to be of the same class type and have B as their base class, while also implementing interface X in the second case, you would typically need to create a class that extends B and implements X. Here's an example in Java:

```
class B implements X { }
class BUsingX extends B implements X { }
B instanceOfB = new B();
BUsingX instanceOfBUsingX = new BUsingX();
```

This way, you would indeed need to create a separate subclass for each combination of base class and interface.

Alternatively, you could consider using composition instead of inheritance. Instead of directly extending B, you could create a wrapper class that implements the required interface and internally holds an instance of B. This can help you achieve similar behavior without creating numerous subclasses:

```
class BWrapper implements X {
private B wrappedInstance = new B();
// Implement methods from interface X by delegating to wrappedInstance
}
BWrapper instanceOfBUsingX = new BWrapper();
```